# Flutter : The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting this error while building project in flutter
under 'url'.

Code:

```
void addProduct(Product product) {
    const url = 'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json';
    http.post(url, body: json.encode({   <-- here 
      'title': product.title,
      'description': product.description,
      'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
      'price': product.price,
      'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
    }),);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try
`const url = Uri.parse('https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json');`